# ExpandableListView groupIndicator is disabled with CheckBox

Tags: android

I am trying to use an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) and in the group view I need a textview and a checkbox (checkbox is on the right).
The issue I am seeing is that the groupIndicator view is no longer tappable - tapping on it does not expand the group anymore. If I remove the checkbox, then groupIndicator receives events and group is expandable. The same happens with another View that receives some kind of focus, for example an EditText.
Here is the layout of the fragment containing the ExpandableListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/categoryList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ExpandableListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout of the group:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCategoryGroup"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/items_filter_group_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <!--
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </CheckBox>
    -->


</LinearLayout>
```

... and, if you find useful, the layout of the child:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/items_filter_child_height"
    android:background="@color/white_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbProperty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </CheckBox>

</LinearLayout>
```

Attached is the layout I am getting if the CheckBox is un-commented: 
[image]

Tapping on the red-marked groupIndicator doesn't expand the group. Leaving it commented expands it. As said above: what is strange is that the same happens with an EditText.

The work-around is to set the groupIndicator to @null and set the TextView's compound left drawable to something relevant in response to [ExpandableListView#OnGroupCollapseListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener.html) and [#OnGroupExpandListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener.html), but I am not that happy writing code for something like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in both LinearLayout of the group and child.